# SafeMath Class. How to create chainable calculations?

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

I'm having a hard time finding the keywords to search for this online.

I've created a class with safe math functions.  Each function takes 2 arguments and after being evaluated by an assertion, it returns the result.

Example:

```
class SafeMath {

  static add(x: number, y: number) {
    let z: number = x + y;
    assert(z >= x, 'ds-math-add-overflow');
    return z;
  }

  static sub(x: number, y: number) {
    let z: number = x - y;
    assert(z <= x, 'ds-math-sub-underflow');
    return z;
  }

  static mul(x: number, y: number) {
    let z: number = x * y;
    assert(y == 0 || z / y == x, 'ds-math-mul-overflow');
    return z;
  }

  static div(x: number, y: number) {
    let z: number = x / y;
    assert(x > 0 || y > 0, 'ds-math-div-by-zero');
    return z;
  }

}

console.log(SafeMath.add(2,2)); // 4
console.log(SafeMath.sub(2,2)); // 0
console.log(SafeMath.mul(2,2)); // 4
console.log(SafeMath.div(2,2)); // 1
```

My goal was to have these functions work like this, for example:

```
let balance0: number = 1;
let balance1: number = 1;

let amount0In: number = 10;
let amount1In: number = 10;

let balance0Adjusted: number = balance0.mul(1000).sub(amount0In.mul(3));
let balance1Adjusted: number = balance1.mul(1000).sub(amount1In.mul(3));
```

...the functions would take in `y` and use the previous number as `x`.

Comment: `1` is a number, it doesn't have a `mul` method. If you start with `let balance0: SafeNumber = new SafeNumber(1);`, you can define your own methods in a `SafeNumber` class.

Comment: Btw, are you trying to represent unsigned integers? JS uses floating point numbers for everything, which do not overflow. And notice your `add` and `sub` method don't work with negative integers.

Comment: Correct on Unsigned Integers. Correct on `add` and `sub` intentionally not working with negative integers.

Comment: Ok, but `x + y` is not addition of unsigned integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `Number.prototype` to add functions so that you can chain these operations. Doing so using `string` property keys is generally considered a bad practice (see [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)). You can use unique [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) property keys instead of string property keys to avoid name conflicts, etc.

Here is an example module which safely "extends" `Number.prototype` with a multiplication function using a unique symbol and adds to the TypeScript `Number` interface the new function signature:

**mul.ts**

```
const mul = Symbol("multiply");

function value(this: number, n: number) {
  return this * n;
}

declare global {
  interface Number {
    [mul]: typeof value;
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, mul, { value });

export default mul;
```

After defining a module like the above for subtraction, addition, division, etc. you can then import the modules and use their exported unique symbols to chain operations:

```
import mul from "./mul.ts";
import sub from "./sub.ts";

const balance = 1;
const amountIn = 10;
const balanceAdjusted = balance[mul](1000)[sub](amountIn[mul](3));
console.log(balanceAdjusted);
```

```
970
```

A nicety of making these math operations chainable is that you can combine them with the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) whenever you're dealing with nullish values which can come in handy sometimes.

---

The same can be done without using symbols but it isn't safe against future versions of JavaScript that might define their own `Number` methods for `mul`, etc:

**mul.ts**

```
function value(this: number, n: number) {
  return this * n;
}

declare global {
  interface Number {
    mul: typeof value;
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, "mul", { value });

export {}; // you have to import or export something to make it a module
```

```
import "./mul.ts";
import "./sub.ts";

const balance = 1;
const amountIn = 10;
const balanceAdjusted = balance.mul(1000).sub(amountIn.mul(3));
console.log(balanceAdjusted);
```

```
970
```

---

Importing all of these modules individually may not be very convenient so you can also make a single module to combine all the others:

**math.ts**

```
export { default as mul } from "./mul.ts";
export { default as sub } from "./sub.ts";
/* and so forth */
```

Then you can import it and select the ones you want to use:

```
import { mul, sub } from "./math.ts";

const balance = 1;
const amountIn = 10;
const balanceAdjusted = balance[mul](1000)[sub](amountIn[mul](3));
console.log(balanceAdjusted);
```

Comment: Very handy. Very sometimes. I don't suppose it's possible to do it with dots eh?

Comment: It is by using `mul` instead of `[mul]` but then if `Number.prototype` later defines its own `mul` method it could cause issues if it behaves differently, etc.

Comment: I've updated my answer with unsafe example code added.

Comment: Sweet. Lastly, I am trying to find a way to have just one import containing all functions. Not one for every single math function I create/wanna use.  When I try to change the function name from `value` to `multiply` I get and error. Keep in mind I am aware of `Number.prototype.add =...` but like you safe approach.

Comment: Personally I would define them all in separate modules/files and then have a single module/file that combines them all using multiple re-export statements like `export { default as mul } from "./mul.ts";` and do forth; that way you can import all of them from one module and use the ones you want

Answer (score 2):

You can make some wrapper for that:

```js
if (!Number.prototype.mul)  // check that the mul method does not already exist 
  {
  Number.prototype.mul = function(n){ return this * n }
  }
  
if (!Number.prototype.add)
  {
  Number.prototype.add = function(n){ return this + n }
  }
  
  
let val = 5
let doubleValPlus500 = val.mul(2).add(500)

console.log( doubleValPlus500 )
```

Comment: error: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'mul' does not exist on type 'Number'.

Comment: @suchislife if it works in "simple" JS, I imagine the syntax in typeScript is different ...

Comment: I'm creating a typescript version based on @Bergi's. Let's see what we get.

Comment: @suchislife I don't know the typescript, I still looked for examples of typescript wrappers, and indeed there are, but the syntactic rules of the typescript escape me completely!

Comment: @MisterMojo, take a look at deno.land

Answer (score 0):

#### Number.prototype based example

```
import { assert } from "https://deno.land/std@0.102.0/testing/asserts.ts";

declare global {

  /*
    Augument global Number.prototype with the following custom functions

    Warning - While this may look like a clean approach, it is considered 
    unsafe due to javascript possibly choosing to natively implement these
    exact function names in the near future. To avoid this, choose unique
    function names.

  */
  interface Number {
    add(n: number): number;
    sub(n: number): number;
    mul(n: number): number;
    div(n: number): number;
    pow(n: number): number;
    sqrt(): number;
    print(): number;
  }
}

Number.prototype.add = function(this:number, n:number) {

  assert((this + n) >= this, 'ds-math-add-overflow');
  return this + n;
}

Number.prototype.sub = function(this:number, n:number) {

  assert((this - n) <= this, 'ds-math-sub-underflow');
  return this - n;
}

Number.prototype.mul = function(this:number, n:number) {

  assert(n == 0 || (this * n) / n == this, 'ds-math-mul-overflow');
  return this * n;
}

Number.prototype.div = function(this:number, n:number) {

  assert(this > 0 || n > 0, 'ds-math-div-by-zero');
  return this / n;
}

Number.prototype.pow = function(this:number, n:number) {

  assert(this > 0 && n >= 2, 'ds-math-exp-to-zero');
  return this ** n;
}

// babylonian method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method)
Number.prototype.sqrt = function(this:number) {

  assert(this > 0, 'ds-math-sqrt-of-zero');

  let x: number = 0;
  let y: number = this;
  let z: number = 0;

  if (y > 3) {
    z = y;
    x = y / 2 + 1;
    while (x < z) {
      z = x;
      x = (y / x + x) / 2;
    }
  } else if (y != 0) {
    z = 1;
  }
  return z;
}

Number.prototype.print = function(this:number) {

  console.log('=', this);
  return this;
}

// Here it is in action:

let balance = 0;

balance.add(10).print().sub(1).print().mul(2).print().div(3).print().pow(4).print().sqrt().print();
```

Output:

```
= 10
= 9
= 18
= 6
= 1296
= 36
```

#### Class based example

```
import { assert } from "https://deno.land/std@0.102.0/testing/asserts.ts";

class SafeMath {
  private n: number;

  constructor(start: number = 0) {
    this.n = start;
  }

  public add(y: number) {

    assert(this.n + y >= this.n, 'ds-math-add-overflow');

    let z: number = this.n + y;

    this.n = this.n + y;
    return this;
  }

  public sub(y: number) {

    assert(this.n - y <= this.n, 'ds-math-sub-underflow');

    let z: number = this.n - y;

    this.n = this.n - y;
    return this;
  }

  public mul(y: number) {

    assert(y == 0 || (this.n * y) / y == this.n, 'ds-math-mul-overflow');

    let z: number = this.n * y;

    this.n = this.n * y;
    return this;
  }

  public div(y: number) {

    assert(this.n > 0 || y > 0, 'ds-math-div-by-zero');

    let z: number = this.n / y;

    this.n = this.n / y;
    return this;
  }

  public pow(y: number) {

    assert(this.n > 0 && y >= 2, 'ds-math-exp-to-zero');

    let z: number = this.n ** y;
    this.n = this.n ** y;
    return this;
  }

  // babylonian method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method)
  public sqrt() {

    assert(this.n > 0, 'ds-math-sqrt-of-zero');

    let x: number = 0;
    let y: number = this.n;
    let z: number = 0;

    if (y > 3) {
      z = y;
      this.n = z;
      x = y / 2 + 1;
      while (x < z) {
        z = x;
        this.n = z
        x = (y / x + x) / 2;
      }
    } else if (y != 0) {
      z = 1;
      this.n = z
    }
    return this;
  }

  public print() {
    console.log('=', this.n);
    return this;
  }

}

// Here it is in action:

new SafeMath(0).add(10).print().sub(1).print().mul(2).print().div(3).print().pow(4).print().sqrt().print();
```

Output:

```
= 10
= 9
= 18
= 6
= 1296
= 36
```